# Ember Web Application with Form based Authentication in Tomcat

Tags: authentication, tomcat, ember.js

I am new to Ember. I have created an Ember application which uses Tomcat Form based authentication. When I hit the protected URL, the protected page gets loaded instead of the page getting redirected to the login route. How do I use Form Based authentication in Tomcat with my Ember App ?